# Ajax to submit a button click to php, then to a serial device

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, arduino

I am trying to get button to to initiate a function on a serial device, an arduino, by means of ajax  and php, but cannot seem to figure it out.

Here is my html:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
 $(function() { 
  $('#contact_form').on('submit', function (e) { 
   e.preventDefault();
   $.ajax({ 
       type: "POST",
    url: '/test/SubmitFormWORefresh.php',
    data: $('#contact_form').serialize(),
       success: function() {
     alert('form was submitted');
          
    }
     });
     return false;
  });
 });
 </script>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Enroll</title>
</head>
<div id="contact_form">
<form name="contact" action="">
  <fieldset>
    <input type="submit" name="rcmd" class="button" id="submit_btn" value="Enroll" /><br />
  </fieldset>
</form>
</div>
```

And here is my php:

```html
<?php
$verz="1.0";
$comPort = "/dev/ttyACM0"; /*change to correct com port */
$PHP_SELF="index.php"; //This php file locate it from root

if (isset($_POST["rcmd"])) {
 $rcmd = $_POST["rcmd"];
 switch ($rcmd) {
      case Stop:
  $fp =fopen($comPort, "w");
  sleep(2);
    fwrite($fp, 1); /* this is the number that it will write */
    fclose($fp);
    break;
  
    case Enroll:
  $fp =fopen($comPort, "w");
  sleep(2);
    fwrite($fp, 3); /* this is the number that it will write */
    fclose($fp);
    break;
  default:
    die('Crap, something went wrong. The page just puked.');
 }/*end switch case*/
}/*end if statement*/
?>
```

When I run it, I get the dialog box that says the form was submitted, but the serial device does not respond to it. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Change `case Stop:` to `case "Stop":` and same thing for `case Enroll:`

Comment: Input type submit is not in serialize function of jquery !

Comment: Alright I did not know that! Im sorry I have just been trying to piece together things.

Comment: Should I even use the serialize function to send the submission to the php?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I change listenner to detect click on button and i get the value with `$(this).val()`

Javascript :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {  
    $('#contact_form').on('click', '.button',function (e) { 
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({    
            type: "POST",
            url: '/test/SubmitFormWORefresh.php',
            data: 'rcmd='+$(this).val(),
            success: function() {
                alert('form was submitted');

            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

Html :

```
<input type="button" class="button" id="submit_btn" value="Enroll" />
```

Comment: Alright so I am getting some feedback from the php script, but the value sent from ajax seems to not match any of my cases. The php ends in the die command stating their is something wrong.

Comment: Did you see my comment : Change `case Stop: to case "Stop":` and same thing for `case Enroll:`

Comment: Yes I did. I don't know why, but it is not meeting any of the cases. Sorry for all the confusion, I have been working on this for the past 5 hours.

Comment: I have edited ` $('#contact_form').on('click', '.button',function (e) { ` i make an error i forget `.` sorry

Comment: WOW, you don't understand how much I appreciate that!!